# C++ How can I append an int to an int?

Tags: c++, int, append

How can I append an int to an int:

```
x = 23;
y = 54;

result = 2354;
```

I hope you help me.

Comment: That's some 4th elementary class math question? Are you serious?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about simple math.

Comment: It looks like a programming question only as he used the word "int".

Comment: Just because it seems obvious to you, doesn't mean it is to everyone else. This is a programming question, although it's not language specific. +1 since this is a legitimate, albeit simple, question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two general approaches:

1. "Shift" the left integer over by multiplying by the appropriate power of 10 and then add the right integer. In the example code that is `x * 100 + y` (or `x * pow(10,2) + y`) as shown in a comment.

   The value to shift can be derived from the ceiling of the log<sub>10</sub> of the right number. Using the math above, this could be expanded more generally as `x * pow(10, ceil(log10(y))) + y`.
2. Convert the integers to strings, *concatenate* the strings, and convert the resulting string back to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Take the inputs as a string
2. concatenate the strings. **or** you can use [append](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/) to add the strings.